# Get file path of movie playing in VLC

Tags: bash, vlc

If VLC is running, playing a movie at file path X, is there any way I can know what file path X is from a Bash script? (For simplicity's sake we can assume that only one instance of VLC is running.)

**Update:** I now know this can be done using the following methods. Are there other ways, perhaps a way of asking VLC directly?

1. AppleScript (macOS only)
2. `lsof` (All Unix)

Answer (score 3):

That's an easy one

`osascript -e 'tell application "VLC" to get path of current item'`

That returns the path to the currently playing movie. If you want more I suggest you select "Open Dictionary.." in the File menu of "Script Editor", select `VLC` and have a good look. Then do `man osascript` on the command line for the man page of osascript.

Answer (score 2):

[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246913/how-to-get-the-title-of-the-media-playing-in-vlc-or-other-media-players-using-cl) suggests a generic way using `lsof`:

```
lsof -wc VLC | awk '$4~"[0-9]r" && $5=="REG"' | grep -o '/.*'
```

This method includes a couple of system files too, but these can be easily removed with `grep`.